# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /mytheme/functions.php on line 43

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /mytheme/functions.php on line 43

```
// Add woocommerce support
$start_extended_woo = get_option( 'swp_woo' );
if( $start_extended_woo[0] == 'Enable' ){
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
add_action( 'init', 'woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
function woo_remove_wc_breadcrumbs() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
}
}
```

Im getting this error after upgrading php from 7.4 to php 8.0 any idea how to fix this?

The them im using is Start Wp Theme, Unfortunately it hasnt been updated in 3 years

Comment: This has always been occurring, it's just that upgrading to PHP 8 raised it from a notice to a warning, and your environment is probably set up not to show notices. As for the fix, the error is pretty explanatory, you need to check if your variable is an actual array before trying to access an offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) `get_option()` returns `false` if it cannot find the option. It's likely your option doesn't exist anymore. To keep it "safe" change to

```
if( is_array($start_extended) && $start_extended_woo[0] == 'Enable' ){
```

This will prevent the exact error your referencing.

Another way would be to change the `get_option()` call to:

```
$start_extended_woo = get_option( 'swp_woo' , ['Disabled'] );
```

This will return the, presumed, opposite of your call.

Alternately, add an option for `swp_woo` in the database, without any code changes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding both code but in this case my header dissapears totally. In php 7.4 my header is visible, in php 8 it dissapears and shows the eeror, your code fixed the error but the header is still missing. any idea?

Comment: My guess is, as implied by the fix, your theme/plugin/option is no longer enabled, and the header is part of that. You may need to re-enable it or force enable it by adding the option `swp_woo` => `Enable` to the `wp_options` table.